# Confluent hypergeometric function for integer values in a closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, special-functions

I have an issue about finding expression involving finite summation for $_1F_1(mn,n,\delta x)$ where $m$ and $n$ are integer and $m,n>1$ for my case. I found an expression in [T.o.I. 3.383.$1^{11}$]

$$ \int_0^u x^{v-1}(u-x)^{\mu-1}e^{\beta x}dx = \mathcal{B}(\mu,v)u^{\mu+v-1} {_1F_1}(v,\mu+v,\beta u), \quad Real\left\{\mu,u\right\}>0$$
where $\mathcal{B}(.,.)$ is well-known Beta function. It seemed quite useful in the beginning, assuming $\mu$ is an integer and applying the binomial expansion to the $(u-x)^{\mu-1}$ term, I thought that I was gonna obtain what I seek. However,  when I apply my case, $(m>1,n \in Z)$ violates the assumption $ Real\left\{\mu,u\right\}>0$. 
Briefly, have you got any idea to express $_1F_1(mn,n,\delta x)$  when $m,n>0 \in Z$ ?

Comment: $B(u, v)$ should be $B(\mu, v)$. There is an identity
$${_1 \hspace {-1.5px} F_1}(a; b; z) =
e^z {_1 \hspace {-1.5px} F_1}(b - a; b; -z),$$
which gives a finite sum since $b - a = n (1 - m) \in \mathbb Z^-$.

Comment: Thank you! Have you got a reference for this identity? and can I apply this for positive $z$ values?

Comment: The formula Maxim speaks about is one of Kummer's transformations.  See Digital Library of Mathematical Functions 13.2.39.